# Why is my function not seeing the check when returning to the previous page?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a first page that has a checkbox.
If the checkbox is selected, the hidden div is shown.
When returning to the first page from the second, the checkbox remains selected, but the div is hidden. Please help me solve this problem.

Checkbox:

```
<div class="checkbox">

    <label style='user-select: none'><input type="checkbox" name="chk" id="exceptions" value="1">Exceptions</label>

</div>
```

div:

```
<div class="panel panel-default" id="exceptionsPanel">
    <div class="panel-heading">Available Exceptions</div>
    <div class="panel-body form-group">
        <label for="exceptionsSelect">Exceptions:</label>
        <select
            name="exceptionsSelect"
            id="exceptionsSelect"
            class="selectpicker"
            data-width="20%"
            data-live-search="true"
            data-size="10"
            multiple
            data-actions-box="true"
            title="Select Exception"
        >
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

function:

```
let exception = $('#exceptions');
$(function () {

    if (exception.prop('checked') == true) {

        $('#exceptionsPanel').show();

    } else {

        $('#exceptionsPanel').hide();

    }

});
```

Previous button on the second page:

```
<div class="text-center">

    <button

        type="button"

        class="btn btn-default"

        id="prevButton"

        onclick="history.back();"

        value="Back"

    >Prev

    </button>

</div>
```

I have no idea how to solve this problem

Comment: Please specifically state what you want to do, ie "I want both checkbox and div to be reset when I navigate from p2 back to p1". Thanks.

Comment: I want the div not to be hidden from the page. But if you have no idea how to do it, then your option is also suitable. Thank you!

Comment: Could it be your `let exception = $('#exceptions');` is executing before the page loads? What happens if you tuck that into the `$(function` right below it?

Comment: @Kinglish tried it, same result

Comment: @AlExp you have to use local storage to maintain the state

Answer (score 0):

you have to maintain the state using localstorage. This should work.

```js
$(function() {
  let flag = localStorage.getItem("flag_show");

  $('#exceptions').on('change', function() {

    if (this.checked) {
      $('#exceptionsPanel').show();
      localStorage.setItem("flag_show", this.checked);
    } else {
      $('#exceptionsPanel').hide();
      localStorage.removeItem("flag_show");
    }
  });

  if (flag) {
    $('#exceptions').trigger('change');
  }


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkbox">

  <label style='user-select: none'><input type="checkbox" name="chk" id="exceptions" value="1">Exceptions</label>

</div>

<div class="panel panel-default hide" id="exceptionsPanel" style='display: none'>
  <div class="panel-heading">Available Exceptions</div>
  <div class="panel-body form-group">
    <label for="exceptionsSelect">Exceptions:</label>
    <select name="exceptionsSelect" id="exceptionsSelect" class="selectpicker" data-width="20%" data-live-search="true" data-size="10" multiple data-actions-box="true" title="Select Exception">
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="text-center">

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="prevButton" onclick="history.back();" value="Back">Prev

    </button>

</div>
```

Comment: For some reason, when returning from the second page to the first, checking for the checked one, does not see the selected checkbox, only when you manually click on the checkbox, then the function works correctly

Comment: @AlExp I tested this locally it works fine. I tried both the scenarios. did you test with the localstorage changes?

Comment: yeah I tested it with localstorage changes, I did exactly the same code

Comment: check if there is value stored in local storage? try to debug this code